# Boto 3 AWS data quality unable to get data_quality result?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I am running a AWS Glue job with data quality check. Using boto3 I am trying to the data quality result by following snippet. But I am unable to get the result. Result ID I am referring to seem to be correct, and I am using current credentials as I can invoke jobs from my code.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('glue')
response = client.get_data_quality_result(
  ResultId='jr_b3f3fb689d0967c1d8af7a992d17709fd82fcbc35ee1e60133fe3ae4179ea3e3'
)
print(response)
```

Error : botocore.errorfactory.EntityNotFoundException: An error occurred (EntityNotFoundException) when calling the GetDataQualityResult operation: Cannot find Data Quality Result in account XXXXXXX with id jr_b3f3fb689d0967c1d8af7a992d17709fd82fcbc35ee1e601.

[image: Image for quality result]